# Dominant seventh

Tags: theory, chord-theory, musicology

I just watched a video about music theory and the guy in the video sounded as if there is a difference between

AMaj7 which would A C# E G

And something he called an "A major dominant seven"

Is there a difference?

Comment: If learning music properly is in any way important you: Get hold of a good, reliable theory book - check Amazon and look at the reviews. Or get yourself a teacher - or both.  Do not rely on random online videos for your music education.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amaj7 is an A major chord with a maj7 note attached. A C# E G#. A dom7 (A7) is A major with a flat 7. A C# E G. Am7 is an A minor chord with a minor 7 attached. A C E G. Am maj7 is A minor chord with a major 7 attached. A C E G#. That's about it. Maybe post a link to the video - which sounds spurious!

Comment: _That's about it._  Indeed. Too bad I can't up-vote again now....

Answer (score 1):

We're in a morass of terminology here!

In terms of describing stand-alone chords, A major (A, C#, E) is just called A.

A7 is A, C#, E, G.

This is sometimes called a 'dominamt 7th' chord type, though it isn't being the dominant of anything at the moment.  It could be the first chord of a Blues in A major.  It could be the dominant 7th chord in D major (or minor).   It could be II7 in G major (yes, it can include a note not in the G scale and still be 'in G major'.  Latch on to that idea folks, you'll need it a lot).  It could be all sorts of other things.  A substitute dominant-function chord in Db major perhaps.

Amaj7 is A, C#, E, G#.   The 'major' part of the name refers to the major 7th, G#.

The dominant 7th OF A major is E7.   But now we're talking about what a chord DOES, not what it IS.

Comment: Question: _it isn't being the dominant of anything at the moment_ - doesn't the structure of the chord make it dominant with respect to itself because of the tritone separating C# from G, which needs to resolve? Or is that only relevant with respect to another contrasting chord or note?

Comment: A dom7 type chord doesn't HAVE to resolve.  The classic example of it not resolving is a Blues progression.   Dominant is as dominant does.

Comment: OK - I understand what you mean - it's a "dominant type" chord that cannot "DOMINATE" anybody else when it's standing alone. In a blues progression everybody is dominant, so nobody is "dominating" anybody else - they are all peers. :) Tnx.

Answer (score -3):

Amaj7 is A C# E G

A major **dominant** seventh starts on the **dominant** (5th) note of the A major scale, which is E, so it would be E G# B D

Comment: This is no definition of the dominant 7th chord that I have ever heard. A7 comes from the 5th mode of the D major scale, if you want to think of it as derived from a scale. The chord you describe is E7.

Comment: This is correct, but perhaps misleading in the context of this question!

Comment: @LaurencePayne - how is this correct? Amaj7  would be **A C# E G#** - the chord indicated is A7, not Amaj7, as Tim said. Am I missing something?

Comment: _A major dominant seventh_ - That's a contradiction in terms. A _Major 7th_  is  not a  _Dominant 7th_ . In the key of A we have a Major 7th chord:3rd is C# and 7th is G# - both the 3rd and the 7th are **Major** intervals; a Dominant 7th chord (the default 7th chord)  3rd is C# and 7th is G -  3rd is a **major** interval and 7th is **minor** -which makes it **Dominant** because of the tritone separating the M3 from m7;  A Minor 7th chord C is the 3rd, G is the 7th - both the 3rd and the 7th are **Minor**. (I'll leave out diminished for now...)

Comment: 'This is correct' referred to @David Bowling's comment.  Not to the main answer.

Comment: @Stinkfoot -- I wouldn't say that *A major dominant seventh* is a contradiction in terms, exactly. Obviously the *seventh* can't be described by both the *major* and *dominant* modifiers, *major* goes with the triad quality and *dominant* goes with the 7th. This seems analogous to *A minor major seventh*.

Comment: @LaurencePayne -- there seems to be a difference between "A major dominant seventh" and "the dominant seventh of A major." Maybe the intention was the latter, but this interpretation escaped my attention. *A major dominant seventh* sounds like a chord name, not unlike *A minor major seventh*. BTW, I didn't downvote on this one.

Comment: 'A major dominant 7th' isn't really a thing.   Though we all have to put up with (and try to decipher) lots of loose namings and descriptions.  The notation and/or sound usually make it clear though.  We do too much TALKING about music!

Comment: @LaurencePayne -- I realize that "A major dominant seventh" isn't a thing, but we have to interpret the words we are given. My point was that this phrase, as used in this answer, sounds like a chord name. In fact it uses exactly the same syntactical construction as "A minor major seventh." And chord names seem to be what the posted question is about. And since we _must_ talk about music sometimes, we ought to try to get our language straight. If the answerer meant "the dominant seventh of A major", that is what they should have said. Current language is, at best, confusing; at worst confused.

Comment: I see we agree, then!

Comment: @DavidBowling - A Major 7th chord is not a Dominant 7th chord. The adjective - Major or Dominant - is referring to the 7th in this case - and the 7th cannot be Major AND Dominant. We have enough confusion as it is, let's try and keep it under control. :)

Comment: @Stinkfoot -- yes, and I don't think that I ever suggested that Amaj7 is the same as A7. I was merely pointing out that the phrase "A major dominant seventh" is inherently confusing. The only way to make sense of it is if you _already_ know that there is no chord with this name.

Comment: @DavidBowling - _already know that there is no chord with this name_ - because it is entirely incorrect should not be used. **That's my story and I'm sticking to it.** :)

Comment: @Stinkfoot -- I only wish I knew what we were arguing about ;)

Comment: @DavidBowling - we're not "arguing", we're just "having a discussion". I am still your friend. :)  I downvoted and "made a stink" here because the question was already well answered a month ago by Tim and the answer was accepted.  This new answer contributes nothing new and contains not one, but two incorrect points so I'm not interested in trying to stretch the incorrect term and accept it on that basis ("in the wild" it might be different). I don't downvote answers very much, especially from someone new, but I thought this one deserved it.

Comment: @Stinkfoot -- Not that a DV was not deserved immediately, but I held off downvoting at first in hopes that the poster would fix what appeared to be a hasty answer, but I see now that they have been back without any attempts to correct. -1 Also, if _you_ can't make a stink, then who?

Comment: @DavidBowling - I did not give myself the name Stinkfoot - it was  bestowed on me by another musician LOL. Done with this.